# Table column with unwanted spacing

Tags: tables

I have a table with two columns.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|p{12cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Company} & \textbf{Contact} \\
\hline
Company produces advanced product systems compatible with a range of blah, blah, and blah used on this and that & Company\\
& 1234\\
& First Street\\
& Troy, New York 12180\\ 
& USA\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The way I have set it out the second column has a blank line which is set by the size of my first column, as you may see in the image below. How can I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want the second column to be wider or do you want the first column to be narrow and wrap the text?

Comment: I am happy with the size of the columns. What is want is to remove the space between 'company' and the next line '1234' in the second column. I want them to be directly ontop of each other without a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like (add `\usepackage{multirow}` in the preamble)?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|p{12cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Company} & \textbf{Contact} \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{12cm}{Company produces advanced product systems compatible with a range of blah, blah, and blah used on this and that} & Company\\
& 1234\\
& First Street\\
& Troy, New York 12180\\
& USA\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

or (`multirow` is not needed)

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|p{12cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Company} & \textbf{Contact} \\
\hline
Company produces advanced product systems compatible with a range of blah, blah, and blah used on this and that & Company%
\newline 1234%
\newline First Street%
\newline Troy, New York 12180%
\newline USA\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Yea, this is what I want....but can I have the text in the first column at the top (i.e., not centered)?

Comment: @Cole see the update

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your `tabular` design, you can nest the right-hand column entries:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|l|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Company} & \textbf{Contact} \\
  \hline
  Company produces advanced product systems compatible with a range of blah, blah, and blah used on this and that &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{4cm}@{}}
    Company \\ 1234 \\ First Street \\ Troy, New York 12180 \\ USA
  \end{tabular} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Make sure that the right-hand, nested `tabular` has a `[t]`op-aligned anchor.