# Unwanted spacing in two column table (how to top align)

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

**Problem description：**
I try to build a table, and wired empty row appear in the first line (see fig 1), how to delete the space, and become a look like fig2 ? That is, how to make the two columns top align.
I do use the multirow like [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119475/table-column-with-unwanted-spacing) did.

**Here is my latex code：**

```
\begin{table}
     \caption{cation}
      \label{tab}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \toprule
             a  & b\\
             \midrule
             \multirow{2}{0.2\textwidth}{xxxxxxxxxxx} & \multirow{10}{0.8\textwidth}{\textbf{xxx}: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\ \emph{xxx}xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (\emph{continues}...)}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
         \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

**fig1 (How it looks like now)：**

[image]

**fig2(what I want)：**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's the purpose of the `\multirow` "wrappers"?

Comment: Hi, the column one is the tile of the content of column two.  Therefore `multirow` is used to wrap the a long sentence that may need two or more rows in column 2. 
For example, think a & b as " Proper nouns"  & " Definition of the noun"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying the `l` column type for both columns and then overlaying `\multirow` wrappers with `p` columns over the cell contents, I think you should use the `p` column type directly, for both columns.

Oh, and do please consider replacing

```
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\  % 7 [!] instances of "\\"
```

with the arguably more-readable

```
\\[6\baselineskip]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
     \caption{caption\strut}
      \label{tab}
        \begin{tabular}{ p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.8\textwidth-4\tabcolsep} }
            \toprule
             a & b\\
             \midrule
             xxxxxxxxxxx & 
             \textbf{xxx}: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
             
             \emph{xxx}xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (\emph{continues}\dots)
             \\[6\baselineskip] 
         \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```